# When using bootstrap analysis, which estimates should be reported, the original ones or the bootstrap derived ones

Tags: bootstrap, reporting

I'm moving more and more to bootstrap for my analyses to estimate the variability of parameters of glm regression models.

I usually report the bootstrap estimate of the parameter (the mean of the bootstrap distribution), but from the theory I know that the bootstrap estimate should approach the original estimate if all $n^n$ possible resamples are evaluated to build the distribution.

So I started to wonder that maybe in the results I should report the original parameter instead of the bootstrap one, together with the bootstrap derived variability statistics (eg, BCa CIs)? Or maybe the bias corrected estimate ($2*\theta-\theta^*$)?

What is the common place and the right thing to do from your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrapping is solely for estimating *variability/precision* not for estimating a point value. You should use the estimate based on your data and use the bootstrap standard errors or confidence interval to report precision (or p-value if you're using boostrapping for a hypothesis test).

Comment: I supposed so...

Comment: I edited the question adding a note about the bias corrected estimate.

Comment: @Bakaburg if there is evidence of bias, then a bias corrected estimate would be preferred, along with some estimate of precision.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on this?